# css change element in same parent

Tags: html, css, input

I want to change an element in the same parent as my input. When my `<input>` is focused I want to change the color of my `<p>` element.

```
<div id="sample">
<input type="text">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

is there a way to do it?

regards
chris

Answer (score 6):

[Adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) CSS selector is used for such cases:

```
input:focus + p
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nf5fV/) using your HTML and my CSS selector that does what you require.

Comment: which version of css is that selector compatible with?